# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Archive[][]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm pushing updates from Angular 5.2.11 to 7.3.9. I'm hitting a types issue that didn't seem to be a problem in the previous version of Angular.

After fixing the import of forkJoin the following code fails with the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/reports/report-measurements-options/report-measurements-options.component.ts(377,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observabl
e<Archive[][]>'.
  Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Archive[][]'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Archive[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

```js
getArchives(): Observable<Archive[][]> {
    if ((this.startDate) > (this.endDate)) {
      let temp = this.startDate;
      this.startDate = this.endDate;
      this.endDate = temp;
    }

    let observableBatch: any[] = [];

    this.selectedBins.forEach(bin => {
      const definition = bin.definitions.find(d => d.type === this.selectedReadingType);

      bin.selectedDefinition = definition;
      bin.definitionUnits = definition.units;

      observableBatch.push(this.archiveService.listArchives(definition.id, this.startDate, this.endDate)
        .map((res: Archive[]) => res));
    });

    return forkJoin(observableBatch);
  }
```

I expect the method to return the correct type and return as it did before the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the type declaration on the method along with using pipe. The following code compiles just fine now:

```js
getArchives() /*removed type*/{
    if ((this.startDate) > (this.endDate)) {
      let temp = this.startDate;
      this.startDate = this.endDate;
      this.endDate = temp;
    }

    let observableBatch: any[] = [];

    this.selectedBins.forEach(bin => {
      const definition = bin.definitions.find(d => d.type === this.selectedReadingType);

      bin.selectedDefinition = definition;
      bin.definitionUnits = definition.units;

      observableBatch.push(this.archiveService.listArchives(definition.id, this.startDate, this.endDate)
        .pipe(map((res: Archive[]) => res)));
    });

    return forkJoin(observableBatch);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see the problem is in this instruction

```
this.archiveService.listArchives(definition.id, this.startDate, this.endDate)
        .map((res: Archive[]) => res)
```

You can remove .map((res: Archive[]) => res) because you are returning the same object, otherwise you upgraded angular from 5 to 7 so the rxjs is also upgraded, to solve this you should use pipe with map like this:

```
this.archiveService.listArchives(definition.id, this.startDate, this.endDate)
            .pipe(map((res: Archive[]) => res))
```

Comment: I was able to solve this issue, but only partly from your solution. I did need to use pipe with map. I think the main issue was coming from declaring the method as a type of ```Observable<Archive[][]>```.